# For Loop Countprime

Tags: count, primes

I have created this code and I received a comment that says:

> "The for loop in the countPrimes method does not count from 0 to the
>   entered value".

I don't understand, can you tell me what does this comment mean?

```
private static boolean isPrime(int prime) {
    if (prime <1 || prime % 2 == 0){
        return false;
    }

    for(int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(prime) ; i++) {
        if ((prime % i) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


/**
 * Count howmany prime exsit between user input and 10,000.
 * @param test if the number is prime.
 * @return the number of primes are found.
 */
private static int countPrimes(int userInput){
    int count =0;
        for(int i=userInput; i<=MAX_PRIME; i++) {
            if(isPrime(i)){
                count++;
            }
        }
    return count;   
    }
```

Comment: does this find optimus prime?

Comment: The comment inline says count how many primes exist between entered number to 10,000 which is your MAX_PRIME value i assume so it does not need to count primes before inputvalue. I am not sure if the comment made is valid or the comment inline is valid. Set your Max_Prime to 10000 and it will do what inline comments say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that it doesn't do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<=userInput; i++)
```

And that's all there is to say about it, really. You should have asked the person who made the commment, IMO.